# How to change the order of a LiveData List?

Tags: java, android, android-room

I'm trying to change the order in which the wrestlers are displayed in my RecyclerView. I want to give the user the option displaying the list by first name in Ascending, Descending, and Random order. How can I change the order of the items in the LiveData list?

The list of Wrestlers is stored in a Room Database, I query the database for all the wrestlers in ascending order by default.

**WrestlersDao**

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM wrestler_table WHERE ORDER BY mFirstName :sortOrder 
    LIMIT :size")
    LiveData<List<WrestlersEntity>> getAllWrestlers(int size, String sortOrder);
```

**MainActivityViewModel**

```
private LiveData<List<WrestlersEntity>> mWrestlersList;
```

The mWrestlersList is displayed in my RecyclerView.

**MainActivity**

```
mMainActivityViewModel.getWrestlersList().observe(this, wrestlersEntities -> {
    adapter.submitList(wrestlersEntities);
});
```

I was thinking I could Query the Database again, would I have to create a new query in the DAO to change the order of the LiveData List, I'm not sure if there is a way to change the ASC programmatically in the original query.

The other option that sounds like it might work is to use a Transformation.map, but I'm struggling to understand this concept.

MainActivityViewModel

```
Transformations.map(mWrestlersList) {
    Collections.shuffle((List<?>) mWrestlersList);
}
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the column-name and sort-order as parameters; eg. for sorted pagination:

```
// getAllWrestlers("mFirstName", "ASC", 50, 0);
@Query("SELECT * FROM wrestler_table ORDER BY :columnName :sortOrder LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset")
LiveData<List<WrestlersEntity>> getAllWrestlers(String columnName, String sortOrder, int limit, int offset);
```

Because unless passing them as parameters, one cannot really control the result-window.

Comment: I'm Not sure what I'm doing wrong, the: sortOrder in the Query is giving me an error, I included the error below.

Comment: (', '.', ASC, BETWEEN, COLLATE, DESC, IN, LIMIT, comma or semicolon expected, got ':sortOrder – Shawn yesterday

Comment: @Shawn you might be missing parameter `String sortOrder`.

Comment: This doesn't work, as the result of all the sorting queries will give the same data set, the observerable will not be notified